# Where can I download the library .jar-files for Akka 2.5.6?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, akka

I would like to update from Akka 2.4.10 to the current Akka 2.5.6. For any reasons I can't find a Download-Link on https://akka.io. On Github I found the source files but what I'm looking for are the compiled .class-files bundled in .jar-files, so that I can directly integrate them as library in IntelliJ IDEA. (With version 2.4.10 there was a file "akka_2.11-2.4.10.zip" available for download at https://akka.io, which had these .jar-files in the "lib"-subdirectory.)

Comment: Your IDE or whatever build system should be able to resolve it w/o any manual d/l, otherwise it's wrong

Answer (score 2):

You can get the JARs directly from [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3Acom.typesafe.akka%20v%3A2.5.6), but you should really consider using a build management tool like SBT. You don't even have to install anything, you can just use the one bundled with IntelliJ. Simply create a file named `build.sbt` in the root of your project with these contents (taken straight from the [Akka documentation](https://akka.io/docs/)):

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.5.6",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-testkit" % "2.5.6" % Test
)
```

Open it in IntelliJ and a bar should appear on top of your editor window, prompting you to import the file. This will take care of downloading the appropriate JARs (along with any dependencies).

Answer (score 1):

You should update akka dependency version and your build system would automatically fetch the necessary jar files compatible with the scala version. From [here](https://mvnrepository.com/search?q=akka) you can find all akka libraries published to maven repository.